# Datatable jquery Time in different Browsers

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, datatable, cross-browser

Inside my Datatable I calculate the time from create date to now:

```
{
                    data: "created_on",
                    targets: [0],
                    render: function (d) {
                        var date = moment(d).format("YYYY.MM.DD");
                        let sortDate = moment(d).format("YYYY.MM.DD hh:mm");
                        
                        var time = moment(d);

                        var eventdate = moment(date);
                        var todaydate = moment();

                        var eventtime = moment(time);
                        var todaytime = moment();

                        if(todaydate.diff(eventdate, 'days') == "0"){

                            if(todaytime.diff(eventtime, 'hours') == "0") {

                                return '<span class="hidden">' +sortDate+ '</span><div>'+ todaytime.diff(eventtime, 'minutes') +' min</div>';

                            } else {

                                const min = todaytime.diff(eventtime, 'minutes') - (todaytime.diff(eventtime, 'hours') * 60);
                                return '<span class="hidden">' +sortDate+ '</span><div>' + todaytime.diff(eventtime, 'hours') + ' Stunden </div><div>' + min + ' min</div>';
                            }
                                
                        } else if (todaydate.diff(eventdate, 'days') == "1") {
    
                            return '<span class="hidden">' +sortDate+ '</span><div>' + todaydate.diff(eventdate, 'days') + ' Tag</div>';
    
                        } else {

                            return '<span class="hidden">' +sortDate+ '</span><div>' + todaydate.diff(eventdate, 'days') + ' Tage</div>';
                        }
                    },
                    width: '100px'
                },
```

My Problem is now that this only works in Chrome and Edge, not in Firefox.

This is the Output for Chrome and Edge:

[image]

And this is the Output in Firefox:

[image]

What can I do about it? Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an Format Error

It needs to be like this:

```
var date = moment(d).format("YYYY/MM/DD");
let sortDate = moment(d).format("YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm");
```